# Frustrating but quite common taking SNAPSHOT problem!

Tags: android, android-activity, snapshot

Taking photos using system provided component(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) is quit common.

As I`ve experimented, with a certain rate the android system will kill the snapshot calling Activity to prevent memory related exception, and the calling activity will be created again where returned. Thus I have to save the states of the calling Activity via onSaveInstanceState, and retrieve them via onRestoreInstanceState. (If I`m not correct and there is further info, please point it out)

However, I also found out that, when the killing occurs, all my information stored in the RAM were ERASED, RESETED, for example those Singleton class type objects, or static classes and their fields!

This mechanism is so frustrating, how to handle such situation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve found it out...

Some android OS kill the snapshot calling Activity to avoid memory related exception. So, I have to save all the states via method onSaveInstanceState, and retrieve them when the calling activity was constructed again.

Further more, I also found out that, all the information stored in the memory is prone to be erased, like those Singleton objects. Thus I have to do saving by some persistent storage approaches, and restore them later.